# How do you open Vine to the camera or a pre-selected video using a URL scheme?

Tags: ios, swift

I've been looking into the url scheme hooks and `vine://` opens the app just fine, but I haven't been able to find a way to open a video in Vine or even open the app right to it's camera.

Have any of you been able to figure this out? Doesn't seem to be much help online

Answer (score 2):

Vine would have to provide a URL Scheme to open the camera directly. There doesn't seem to be any documentation on Vine's URL Schemes so I'd imagine it is not possible.

You can open Vine to a particular video or profile though. For example:

Video:

```
let url = NSURL.init(string: "vine://post/<PostID>")
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
}
```

Profile:

```
let url = NSURL.init(string: "vine://user/<UserID>")
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
}
```

You also need to add `vine` to your info.plist's [LSApplicationQueriesSchemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW14):

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>vine</string>
    </array>
```

Answer (score -1):

I use an app that opens up url schemes and I entered

Vine://camera

I'm not sure if it's only for that specific app (Dashboard Free All In One) but when i entered the url scheme, it opened up the Vine app and went right to the camera.
Hope this helps! :)